# update date from another date value for specific records

Tags: sql, datetime

I have an SQL table with the following fields:

**ID** (auto number)

**Item** (nvarchar)

**CreateDate** (DATETIME)

**UpdateDate** (DATETIME)

I want to change through a script the UpdateDate to be the same as CreateDate for only items having UpdateDate greater than 2015 as year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET UpdateDate = CreateDate
WHERE UpdateDate >= '2015-01-01'
```

**EDIT:** This will include records that have a year of 2015. If you want only the records that have 2016 or higher as the year, use this instead:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET UpdateDate = CreateDate
WHERE UpdateDate >= '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one ..
update your_table set UpdateDate=CreateDate where UpdateDate >= '2015-01-01';